# Bibliography only printing the authors issue

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, citing, miktex

I am having a slight issue whilst trying to do my bibliography for my project. I am seeing the following when I am printing my bibliography:
[image: bad bib]

as seen above, the title the year- literally nothing appears :(. I am using the following to create the bibliography:

```
%Loading in the packages
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{superintro}

\input{chapters/superintro}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I then perform \cite{} within the superintro .tex file and this produces the weird bibliography output.

some of the example citations.bib file looks as follows:

```
@report{ RFC3550,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne, S. Casgner, R. Frederick, V. Jacobson}
    title = {RFC 3550, RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications}
    url = {https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550}
    year = {July, 2003}
}

@report{ RFC2326,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne, A.Rao, R. Lanphier}
    title = {RFC 2326, Real Time Streaming Protocol}
    url = {https://rools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326}
    year = {April, 1998}
}
```

I was hoping for the bibliography to contain all of the information above, and I was also hoping for citations in the body of the document to disply as author-year.

for example please see RFC2326[SCH98].

If anyone could help It would be much appreciated, I have tried changing the style to author year to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get something like

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: tubby.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Database file #1: tubby-blx.bib
Database file #2: tubby.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 3 of file tubby.bib
 :     
 :     title = {RFC 3550, RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications}
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 10 of file tubby.bib
 :     
 :     title = {RFC 2326, Real Time Streaming Protocol}
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Biblatex version: 3.0
(There were 2 error messages)
```

when running BibTeX on the file (I renamed it to `tubby.bib` for not clobbering my files).

Fields in an entry must be terminated by a comma which is optional only after the last field (but I recommend adding it also there).

You also have the `author` fields wrong: authors should be separated by `and`, not by a comma. The `year` field should contain only the year.

In the following example I use `filecontents*`, but just to make the example self-contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@report{RFC3550,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne and S. Casgner and R. Frederick and V. Jacobson},
    title = {RFC 3550, RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications},
    url = {https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550},
    year = {2003},
}

@report{RFC2326,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne and A. Rao and R. Lanphier},
    title = {RFC 2326, Real Time Streaming Protocol},
    url = {https://rools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326},
    year = {1998},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{RFC3550} and \cite{RFC2326}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks very much if I change the styling to author year and seperate them with 'and' will it appear as SCH03 in the text?

Comment: @TubbyTommy I fixed the problem with the year.